# How to clean embedded tomcat cache

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, caching

I am running momentarily into this error when building/running my project locally:

```
Jan 14, 2022 12:06:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFORMATION: Starting tomcat server
Jan 14, 2022 12:06:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Jan 14, 2022 12:06:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /Users/userxy/Desktop/tomtom/tomtom-ws/target/myproject does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat6.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:997)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat6.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I have read that this is related to tomcat cache due to the context of the phantom project. I could not figure out however how to clear my embedded tomcat's cache since I am using `org.codehaus.mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin`. I tried to clean my eclipse's cache by running : `$./eclipse -clean` This did not help me either. I am using JDK `1.7.0_322-zulu`.

Any help will be more than appreciated.

P.S. I have tried to switch to a new workspace but it did not help either